# Can not set a NOW() in datetime field mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

Hello I'm having a hard time trying to update this field automatically when I update something else in that same table called 'reps' the structure of the table is:
id int primary key,
name varchar(10) not null,
date_up datetime

**When I run this query:**

```
SELECT * FROM reps;
```

it shows the information correctly however when I try to update a row of this table the date_up field is not updating... here's my code:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/db/connect.php';
$id = 5;
$name = "LCD Replacement";

$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$statement = $conexion->prepare('UPDATE reps SET name=:name, date_up = NOW() WHERE id = :id');
$statement->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':id' => $id
));
```

when I refresh the page nothing is updated but if I run that same SQL query on the mysql console it work so I don't know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: there should be not a single problem with using mysql functions in the query. Double-check the results and also make sure you can see PHP errors in general. Would your code show an error message if you add a deliberate error in the query?

Comment: Have you tried [`print_r($conexion->errorInfo());`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) after your `execute()`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus he has a PHP fatal error if query fails, so there is absolutely no point in using unreliable errorinfo.